# symfony multiple choicetype isn't prepopulated

Tags: php, forms, symfony

So I have a Symfony 3 form with a multiple ChoiceType list with a few constant options.
Those choices are then saved in a database (manage with doctrine) in a 'json_array' field.

When I save the form, the selected choices are correctly saved in database as :

```
["my.Choice.1","my.Choice.2"]
```

But when I want to edit this form again, none of the selected options are "selected". They stay unchecked.

I have an other field (EntityType, multiple) which is correctly prepopulated with data from database.

**MyEntityType** :

```
$builder
    ->add('myChoices', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
            'choice #1' => MyEntity::CHOICE_1,
            'choice #2' => MyEntity::CHOICE_2,
        ],
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
    ])
```

Here is how my field is defined in the entity.

MyEntity :

```
const CHOICE_1 = 'my.Choice.1';
const CHOICE_2 = 'my.Choice.2';

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="my_choices", type="json_array", nullable=true)
 */
private $myChoices;

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getMyChoices()
{
    return array_unique($this->myChoices);
}

/**
 * @param array $myChoices
 *
 * @return MyEntity
 */
public function setMyChoices(array $myChoices)
{
    $this->myChoices = [];

    foreach ($myChoices as $myChoice) {
        $this->addMyChoice($myChoice);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $myChoice
 *
 * @return MyEntity
 */
public function addMyChoice($myChoice)
{
    $myChoice = strtolower($myChoice);

    if (!$this->hasMyChoice($myChoice)) {
        $this->myChoices[] = $myChoice;
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $myChoice
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasMyChoice($myChoice)
{
    return in_array(strtolower($myChoice), $this->myChoices, true);
}
```

And my form is called like this :

```
$myEntity = ..... // loaded from database
$form = $this->createForm(MyEntityType::class, $myEntity);
```

So is there anybody who can tell my what I am missing ??

Thanks again.

Comment: @Yoshi, yes its a typo, thanks for pointing me at it. I've just edited.

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem (without doctrine) by doing something like: `$foo->setMyChoices(json_decode('["my.choice.1","my.choice.2"]'));` in the controller. With this, both checkboxes are checked. Would you try `dump($myEntity->getMyChoices())` to see what is actually loaded (set up by doctrine) in your code?

Comment: Hi, here is the twig dump : `array:2 [▼
  0 => "my.choice.1"
  1 => "my.choice.2"
]`

Comment: If I dump the form data right after form is created `$form = $this->createForm(MyEntityType::class, $myEntity); var_dump($form->get('choices')->getData());`, I get the correct result : `array (size=2)
  0 => string 'my.choice.1' (length=11)
  1 => string 'my.choice.2' (length=11)`. So why checkboxes arent checked ??

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

All is working like it should.

My mistake is in my choices names, which are containing upper letter`my.Choice.1, ...`

And in my getter and setter, I force strings to be lowercase `strtolower($myChoice)`